# Jest throwing error, "transformIgnorePatterns is not working"

Tags: jestjs

I am writing the unit tests for my JavaScript/ React JS application using Jest testing framework. When I run my test I am getting the following error.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\Users\{user}\{project}\app\node_modules\react-date-picker\node_modules\react-calendar\dist\Calendar.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.react-calendar {
```

The error is coming from the package in the node_modules folder, \react-date-picker.

So to fix that, I changed the jest.config.js file as follow.

```
const esModules = [ 'react-date-picker'].join('|');
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`]
};
```

This is the command for the "npm run unit:test"

```
"jest --watchAll --testPathPattern=tests/unit --config jest.config.js",
```

When I run the test again, I am still getting the same error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A pretty similar case here, he managed to fix it by adding `"allowJs": true` to the `compilerOptions` of each `lib/app`'s `tsconfig.spec.json` (or alternatively to the root `tsconfig.json`) in addition to setting `transformIgnorePatterns`.

See source: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/812

Comment: Can you please show me how can I configure that file, tsconfig.json? I added that file it seems not to be working because the file does not seem to be picked up.

Comment: Sorry I won't be able to do that in a timely manner.